# Is there a way to display the color of a (hex color) field in the Django Admin site?

Tags: python, django, colors, hex

I have a model in Django 3:

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    name_EN = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    hexcolor = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#ffffff")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name_EN
```

This lists Ingredients and has associated a name with it, e.g. 'Dill' or 'Tomato', and a 'hexcolor' e.g. #C5E1A5 or #DD2C00. Currently, from the admin site, I can see the ingredients listed as name_EN of the Ingredient, and when I click through also the hexcolor value (#......). But I would like to see the actual color listed next to the name_EN, so I can see it (and change when needed). It doesn't necessarily need a color picker, could be nice, but I seek in the first place how to display the color (e.g. the background color of the hexcolor field?).

Any suggestions where and how to do this? Would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in [Django3 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display), you can do this by using a method like `colored_name` method as below:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.db import models
from django.utils.html import format_html

class Ingredient(models.Model):

    name_EN = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, null=True)
    hexcolor = models.CharField(max_length=7, default="#ffffff")

    def colored_name(self):
        return format_html(
            '<span style="color: #{};">{}</span>',
            self.hexcolor,
        )


class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name_EN', 'hexcolor', 'colored_name')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems what I am looking for, but haven't been able to get it work yet. I copied your code and the server runs, but as soon as I display the list of Ingredients it breaks.   <br/>  Error: /django/db/models/options.py", line 581, in get_field   return self.fields_map[field_name] KeyError: 'colored_name'  <br/>  Any suggestions welcome!  And sorry for this messy markdown, this is my first on Stackoverflow, and the formatting is not yet intuitive to me.

Comment: According to some searches, I found this error and most of the solutions suggested that deleting all migration files (except \__init.py\__) and running makemigraiton may solve it.Overall, this is another question, and if this answer was helpful, you should accept it according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)